# Error en Registro Android String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un registro en Android pero cuando le doy al boton "Registrar Incidencia", me genera en el logcat el siguiente error:

[image: Error que me lanza el logcat]

Este es mi RegistrarIncidencias:

```
        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String comprobante = etComprobante.getText().toString();
            final String tipo = etTipoProd.getText().toString();
            final String marca = etMarcaProd.getText().toString();
            final String modelo = etModeloProd.getText().toString();
            final int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(etCantidad.getText().toString());
            final int monto = Integer.parseInt(etMonto.getText().toString());
            final String tipo_incidencia = spTipoIncidencia.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrarIncidencia.this,MenuPrincipal.class);
                            RegistrarIncidencia.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrarIncidencia.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Registro Fallido").setNegativeButton("Intentar",null).create().show();
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(comprobante,tipo,marca,modelo,cantidad,monto,tipo_incidencia,responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegistrarIncidencia.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

Según el logcat los errores están en:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() 

JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

Este es mi archivo .php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","id7687347_lalycorp","lalycorp","id7687347_lalycorp");

$comprobante = $_POST["comprobante"];
$tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
$marca = $_POST["marca"];
$modelo = $_POST["modelo"];
$cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
$monto = $_POST["monto"];
$incidencia_tipo = $_POST["tipo_incidencia"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO laly_incidencias (incidencias_comprobante, incidencias_tipoprod, incidencias_marcaprod, incidencias_modeloprod, incidencias_cantidad, incidencias_monto, incidencias_tipo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isssiis", $comprobante, $tipo, $marca, $modelo, $cantidad,$monto,$incidencias_tipo);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);

 ?>
```

[image: Imagen del log con respuesta]

Anexo mi RegisterRequest:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://lalycorp.000webhostapp.com/RegIncidencia.php";
private Map<String,String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String comprobante, String tipo, String marca, String modelo, int cantidad, int monto, String tipo_incidencia, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("comprobante",comprobante);
    params.put("tipo",tipo);
    params.put("marca",marca);
    params.put("modelo",modelo);
    params.put("cantidad",cantidad+"");
    params.put("monto",monto+"");
    params.put("tipo_incidencia",tipo_incidencia);
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Se muestra logcat sin errores pero cuando voy a la base de datos no hay registros:

[image: LogCat Sin errores]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te recomiendo que hagas un Log.i("respuesta",response para ver que te devuelve)

Comment: adjunto foto de la respuesta que me comentas

Comment: Tienes una clase RegiterReuest? que exteiende de StringRequest

Comment: Si, anexo mi RegisterRequest

Comment: si por favor para ver los parametros

Comment: Anexado, gracias

Comment: $comprobante = $_POST["comprobante"]; debe ser como esta en tu clase register por eso no lo encuetra

Comment: cambia todos los nombre de donde recibes la peticion, dejalos como en tu clase Register

Comment: ok, cambio todo y comento el resultado

Comment: Estas seguro que el parametro `response` del metodo `onResponse` es una cadena con formato json, por que el error dice que el valor `<br` de tipo cadena no se puede convertir a `JSONObject`

Comment: Le cambié los nombres donde recibo mi petición, ahora no me muestra ningún error y el botón "Registrar" funciona, pero los datos no se van registrados a la BD remota ...

Comment: Dado que quieres recuperar los datos por POST, en el servidor debes poner esto al principio del todo: **`$_POST=apache_request_headers();`**,  sin eso no encontrará nunca los datos. Otra cosa curiosa es que, al menos en mi caso, las claves que se pasan en el `map`, son convertidas a la primera letra en mayúscula. O sea, si pasas esto: `params.put("comprobante",comprobante);` y luego intentas recuperarlo con `$_POST["comprobante"]` no lo encuentra, tienes que poner `$_POST["Comprobante"]`. De todos modos, si quieres verificar cómo están los datos puedes hacer `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que la respuesta en realidad no es un .json, por esa razón al tratar de crear un objeto json se genera un error:

```
  JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

debes asegurar que tu petición genere el .json adecuado.

Estas recibiendo un html, por errores en la url al no enviar los parámetros necesarios. Esto es lo que obtienes y que es incorrecto:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: comprobante in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: tipo in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: marca in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: modelo in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: cantidad in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: monto in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: tipo_incidencia in <b>/storage/ssd2/347/7687347/public_html/RegIncidencia.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
{"success":true}
```

Asegura que los parámetros enviados son correctos:

```
public RegisterRequest(String comprobante, String tipo, String marca, String modelo, int cantidad, int monto, String tipo_incidencia, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("comprobante",comprobante);
    params.put("tipo",tipo);
    params.put("marca",marca);
    params.put("modelo",modelo);
    params.put("cantidad",cantidad+"");
    params.put("monto",monto+"");
    params.put("tipo_incidencia",tipo_incidencia);
}
```

Comment: No entendí muy bien tu explicación (Soy nuevo en android la verdad) osea tengo que crear un archivo .json?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que al realizar la petición la respuesta obtiene un html probablemente es un error en la página @Stalinn tienes la url de tu petición

Comment: Claro la url es: "https://lalycorp.000webhostapp.com/RegIncidencia.php", arriba está el php actualizado

Comment: Si cargas la url directamente podrás ver que obtienes precisamente lo que comento en mi respuesta, debes asegurar enviar los parámetros adecuados

Comment: Eso es lo que me parece raro, también en el ejemplo que seguía de un video en youtube ... también le salía el mismo error cuando entraba a su url pero en a él si le registraba en la bd ... viendo mi bd y lo que envío no encuentro cual estoy enviando de manera incorrecta